# Arduino uno audio output quality improvement

Tags: sound

I am new to electronics. I am going to play a sound truck from SD card when user push a button, Well This is very easy and there are lots of methods and codes to play it. the problem is with sound quality. I want to output sound into an speaker using 2.5 mm jack. here the problem appears. Is there any module which outputs Arduinos to speakers?

To me more clear in this tutorial https://www.instructables.com/id/Audio-Player-Using-Arduino-With-Micro-SD-Card/ we can play sound using simple speakers, is it possible to connect it to a higher quality speaker? like those pc speakers using 2.5 mm jack?
In fact I want to get better sound quality than the above tutorial using adrino.
thanks

Comment: The problem isn't the speakers, but that an Arduino is a terrible sound generator regardless of what you drive with it.  You can ironically do quite a bit better with an ATtiny85.  Otherwise you need something with an actual DAC.  Not sure who dowvnoted your question, but they have a point - there are many project writeups out there online, no need to ask a question here, especially when it is one which is too broad to fit the mission of this site.

Comment: I did not down vote your question.  However it is likely that it was down voted because you are not asking about a specific problem.  I would suggest you delete this question, go out and try something (your link is an excellent starting point) then come back with a well formed question about a specific problem or improvement.  Remember, none of the stackexchange web sites are good for discussions.   They are designed to create a data base of well defined questions and concise answers.

Comment: ...I've changed my mind.  Instead of deleting your question - ask a more specific question about how to get better sound quality than is possible from the example you linked to.

Comment: @st2000 thanks very much. I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a beginner, it is always better to copy then invent.  That said, I would recommend using [this arduino.cc Simple Audio Player tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer).  There are [many different types of Arduino boards](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Products/Compare).  The Arduino Due uses a [Microchip/Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 CPU](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-11057-32-bit-cortex-m3-microcontroller-sam3x-sam3a_datasheet.pdf) which contains at least one [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter).  It is assumed this will produce better sound than the [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) output of the slower [ATmega328P](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/atmega328p) processor found on an Arduino Uno.

Comment: thanks, how can I improve its quality? for example output the audio to an amplifier ?is there any key words which I can search?

Comment: The Simple Audio Player example I linked to in the answer uses an Arduino Due which contains at least 1 DAC.  This likely is an improvement in sound quality over the Arduino Uno which has no DAC, only PWM.  Futher, the Simple Audio Player example uses an OpAmp which appears to be driving a small speaker.  The example I linked to in the answer should have better sound quality then the example you linked to in your question.

Comment: I've re-read your question.  If you want to stick with the Arduino Uno and still want good quality sound you will likely need to push all sound related hardware and processing off the Arduino Uno board as the Arduno Uno is not powerful enough to handle the necessary data nor does it have a DAC.  Consider [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1790) board.

Comment: can't I simply connect the speakers output to an external amplifier? for example connect it using a jack to an speaker with internal amplifier?